# Simple Composisitons

Tags: algebra-precalculus, function-and-relation-composition

I just need someone to check my work before I go on as I am just checking to make sure I am doing it right.

$$g(t) = 2t^2 - 2t ,\ \ \ h(t) = 3t -1$$
$$g(2t^2 - 2t)$$
$$h(g(t)) = 3(2t^2 - 2t) - 1$$
simplified answer of $h(g(t)) = 6t^2 - 6t  - 3$

If anything seems off please let me know, Thanks.

Comment: I don't know why you've written $g(2t^2-2t)$ on the second line, but seems good except for the random $-1$ and $-3$ that show up out of nowhere.

Comment: where does the $-1$ come from?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$h(g(t)) = h(2t^2 - 2t) = 3(2t^2 - 2t) - 1 = 6t^2 - 6t - 1$$

You've subtracted $1$ from $g(t)$ and that error follows you when you multiply through by $3$.

Comment: of course you are right but I don't know why you factor the polynomial term before you multiply all to get the final result.

Comment: I was just showing different ways to represent the answer (last two ways), either fully factored, or fully expanded.

Comment: So the final after correcting the error should be 6t^2 - 6t - 1  right?

Comment: No $-1$ at the end: it should be $6t^2 - 6t$, unless you meant for $h(t) = 3t - 1$. Then $6t^2 - 6t - 1$ would be correct. But as posted, we take $g(t) = 2t^2 - 2t$ and apply $h$ which multiplies g(t) by 3. Period.

Comment: Yeah I typo'd in the original it was suppose to be 3t - 1. Thanks

Comment: That makes sense! I adapted my answer accordingly.

Comment: @amWhy: Nice discourse +1